# unable to check out from a heroku repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have recently installed the heroku toolbelt on a new windows machine. I have added ssh keys but when I run the following command:

```
heroku git clone -a app
```

I receive a permission denied error. There is no mention of it being an ssh error just permission denied.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this?

`heroku git:clone app_name local_path`